# What is the difference between IF and ELSE IF clauses?

Tags: c

I'm on the path of learning C with K&R. Besides the exercises in the book, I'm also doing some by myself. I wrote the following code, what it does is, it counts your input, gives you feedback how many words are left to reach the "goal" of 10 words and congratulates you as soon as you reach the 10 words.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    /* This programm will read your input, check the number of words,
    and will congratulate when you reach a value of 10 words*/

    int c, nw, counter;

    nw = 0;
    counter = 0;

    while (nw < 10)
    {
        c = getchar();

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        {
            counter = 0;
        }

        else if (c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n')
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                counter = 1;
                ++nw;
            }
            printf("Only %d words left\n", 10-nw );
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, in this version the code will not count blanks as words, resulting in the correct output of words left.

At first I wrote the code with only "if" instead of "else if". What it did was it also counted the blanks as words.

The question I am asking is why ? Wheres the difference in using if or else if.

As I understand is, that compiler will check whether a condition is met or not met. This should also be the case when only using if. As everything is the same expect else if instead of if, I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Can you fix your formatting, please? And code reviews might be better placed over at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you think of a single case where `c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n'` is false?

Comment: At first I wanted to downvote and suggest moving it to codereview, but after rereading and noticing the actual question, this seems valid and well-asked question to me. **boso**, you've worked hard to describe the issue, that's great! But please make sure to think+work a little on choosing a good title for your question. "Bad" title can spoil the effect ;)

Comment: @molbdnilo, I try to figure out which case this might be, but for now what I see is that it is true whenever it reads a character of a word and is false whenever one of the space characters is found...

Comment: @boso "_it would be false whenever the input is an integer instead of a character_" -- Nope.

Comment: @boso Assume that the character is `' '`. Then, `c` is unequal to both `'\t'` and `'\n'`. The negation of `a or b` is `(not a) *and* (not b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this might be a case of overthinking a problem. The logic you've ended up with, aside from being wrong, is overly complicated. Your question of the difference between `if` and `else if` is fair, and I promise I will address it in my answer.

First, let me restate what you are trying to do:

> Read input, count number of words, and congratulate you when you reach 10 words

From your code, I believe your intention is to split words based on spaces, tabs, and newlines. There are many ways to split words, but for the purposes of this question, your intended method is fine.

The problem, of course, is that your logic doesn't work. You have a condition that can never be false:

```
else if (c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n')
```

Think about it (hint: the `else` doesn't change the condition itself). Say it out loud if that helps: You are looking for a condition where `c` isn't a space, or `c` isn't a tab, or `c` isn't a newline. Remember that logical or (`||`) is an *inclusive* or, in other words, the expression is `true` if *any* of the conditions are `true`. For example, let's suppose `c` is a space. The first condition (`c != ' '`) fails, but the 2nd one, `c != '\t'` is `true` because a space is not a tab. Thus, the entire expression is `true`. In fact, that expression will be true for *any* value of `c`.

### But what about `else`?

As I said, the `else` part of the `else if` doesn't make a difference here. The only thing `else if` does differently is essentially tack itself on as a new condition to your `if` statement. Let's look at a simpler example:

```
if (a == 1) {
    /* a is 1 */
}

if (a != 1 && b == 2) {
    /* a isn't 1, but b == 2 */
}
```

That's an example of two completely independent `if` statements. It's a perfect example of where to use `else`, because as you probably noticed, the 2nd `if` statement tests for the inverse of the 1st. (`a != 1`). So, the above can be simplified as follows:

```
if (a == 1) {
    /* a is 1 */
else if (b == 2) {
    /* a isn't 1 and b is 2 */
}
```

In the `else if` block, we needn't test for `a != 1`, as that's implied because we only evaluate the `else` statement if the 1st `if` conditional was false.

Note also that `else if` is actually a combination of two separate keywords. It is equivalent to:

```
else {
    if (b == 2) { ... }
}
```

However, by convention we omit the optional braces and write it as:

```
else if (b == 2) { ... }
```

In fact, in some cases we don't need that 2nd `if` at all:

```
if (a == 1) {
    printf("a is 1!\n");
} else {
    printf("a isn't 1. In fact, it's %d.\n", a);
}
```

### Simplified Version

So, now there's no need to get caught up in `else if`. Focus on your logic, and do your best to simplify it. I will simplify it for you, however I encourage you to skip over this part and try it on your own first:

```
char c;
int in_word = 0;

while (nw < 10) {
    c = getchar();

    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
        /* If we were in a word, then count that word! */
        if (in_word) {
            nw++;
            printf("You only have %d words to go!", 10 - nw);
        }
        in_word = 0; /* We are not in a word now */
    } else {
        in_word = 1; /* Now we're in a word
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for. But two separate **if** statements are both evaluated no matter what. With "**if**" and "**else if**", first **if** is evaluated if it is true, **else if** is skipped. When "**if**" is not true "**else if**" is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

```
else if (c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n')
```

This line of code is probably not doing what you intended. It works fine as an `else if`, but in fact it doesn't really check anything (you could actually replace it with a simple `else`)! For any conceivable character, it's will *always* be either not a space, or not a tab, or not a newline. What you really want is the conjunction of those statements, rather than the current disjunction:

```
else if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n')
```

This checks that the character is neither a space, a tab, nor a newline. It would work even with `else` removed, as a separate `if`-statement. However, you really should just go with a simple `else`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` condition, if you use simple `if .. else` construct, it will be equivalent to

```
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') //Notice &&.
                        //Apply De-morgan's law over if conditio.
    {
      ...
    }
```

In the above case `else if` is not required, `if else` is suffice to use. Using `if .. else` would be more efficient than the given code.

However, logically it may have same effect as your given code.

As per logic, `else if` is not required.

The difference you will get in terms of number of comparison operation as explained below.

Current code:

1. For any non-space character such as `'a'`, it will perform 4 comparisons (`||` and `&&` are short-circuited).
2. For any space character, there will be max 3 comparisons.

In `if-else` code, max of 3-comparison will be performed.

This difference is not so significant. And can only be noticed when code is run billions of times.

`if else` has extra advantage of **maintenance.** In the above code in OP, if there is any change in `if` part, it should be reflected in `else if` part also.

Hence, to me it seems it will be beneficial to go with just `if else` rather `if else if`.